# How to play 360 video with seekbar in HTML Google card board VR

Tags: html, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I need assistance for creating **360 Video HTML VR** using **Google Cardboard VR**.

I have downloaded source from below url, I need to integrate seekbar and i need documentation for **360 Video** in **HTML VR**.

https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/index.html